# express is undefined when attempting to mock with jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

Im attempting to mock express using jest in a typescript project. Try a lot of ways of doing this using solutions i've seen on here and express either comes up as undefined or not a function. Im only just getting started with Jest and testing in general.

Heres the test,

```js
import { Server } from '../app/index'
import { AppRouter } from '../app/AppRouter'

jest.mock('../app/AppRouter')

//mock express
const expressMock = {
  use: jest.fn()
}

jest.mock('express', () => () => expressMock)

//mock decorators
jest.mock('../app/controllers/RootController', () => jest.fn())
jest.mock('../app/controllers/LoginController', () => jest.fn())
jest.mock('../app/controllers/decorators/controller', () => jest.fn())

describe('Server test suite', () => {
  test('should create server on port 3000', () => {
    new Server().startServer()
    console.log('test ran')
  })
})
```

heres the code im testing,

```js
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cookieSession from 'cookie-session'
import { AppRouter } from './AppRouter'

import './controllers/LoginController'
import './controllers/RootController'

export class Server {
  private app: express.Express = express()

  public startServer() {
    console.log('Express is:', express())
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
    this.app.use(cookieSession({ keys: ['alsdfsdf'] }))
    this.app.use(AppRouter.getInstance())

    this.app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('Listening on port 3000')
    })
  }
}

new Server().startServer()
```

and the config,

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./build",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "./src",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

Comment: The answer explains what's wrong with the mock but it likely won't be helpful because the purpose is unclear. So Express and controllers were mocked, and what was left to test? There are no controllers in Express so they likely don't need to be tested as separate units. A common approach for Express integration testing is to mock other units (models) and side effects and do requests with Supertest. It doesn't play well with your project . `Server` is a made-up entity that cannot be efficiently tested. A better way is to have `App` (without app.listen) and set up a server in another entry point

Comment: @EstusFlask I was aiming for unit testing rather than integration testing. Maybe test that use was called 3 times, and the server starts?. Should i just do this with actual express instead of mocking it? and then just mock the request and response which ive seen done going forwards in other tests? Not sure what you mean by-"A better way is to have App (without app.listen) and set up a server in another entry point" Thanks for your help!

Comment: In my experience unit tests for route handlers (controllers) separately from the framework aren't worth it because they are very specific to how Express behaves. You can mock some middlewares if you need. I mean that app instance (`app` object with middlewares appied) and server instance (`app.listen(...)` object`) should be created separately in different modules. In tests you want to import app instance but not server instance. See examples for Supertest. Not doing this will make testing more difficult - Jest tests are concurrent and will try to listen to 3000 at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `expressMock` variable can result in `express() === undefined` because it's defined after mocked module is imported, this is explained in the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter).

It should be defined as follows:

```
jest.mock('express', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    use: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
  })
})
```